# Running an exe from C# with arguments that have spaces in

Tags: c#

I am scratching my head with this one.  I am trying to run an exe from C# using system.diagnostics but it isnt passing over my arguments correctly so the exe falls over.

It splits the path after the word 'here' (see below) because of the space in it.

Does anyone know how I can get round this without renaming the directory (which isn't an option for me)

**This works from command line:**

"C:\Users\me\Desktop\myexternalexe\myexternalexe.exe" comments “\192.168.1.1\a\here is the problem\c\d\"

**This doesn't from with in Visual Studio:**

```
Process myexternalexe = new Process();

myexternalexe.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\myexternalexe\myexternalexe.exe";
myexternalexe.StartInfo.Arguments = @"comments \\192.168.1.1\a\here is the problem\c\d\";

myexternalexe.Start();
```

Comment: I'm really not sure about this but try replacing spaces with %20

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But you've omitted the quotes from the C# version. It should be:

```
myexternalexe.StartInfo.Arguments = @"comments ""\\192.168.1.1\a\here is the problem\c\d\""";
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185633/problem-with-spaces-in-a-filepath-commandline-execution-in-c)

In your case following should work.

```
 string folderName = @"\\192.168.1.1\a\here is the problem\c\d\";
 myexternalexe.StartInfo.Arguments= @"comments" + " \"" + folderName  +"\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 alexe.StartInfo.Arguments = "comments \"\\\\192.168.1.1\\a\\here is the problem\\c\\d\\\"";
```