# C# fileName display with spaces trouble

Tags: c#, file, file-io

Suppose I have a report Name as :

```
string reportName = "Facebook Network Performance Summary Report (By Region, By Content)";
```

and I would like to display that file name as excel

the below is my code to export the file

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" reportName + ".xls");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", l.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.BinaryWrite(f);
```

Unluckily, thewhen reading the first space of my reportName, it only shows Facebook and no else.

Is there any wexisting API for ASP.NET or other methods to handle the spaces of fileNAme  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try wrapping the filename in double quotes.**

```
 string filename = reportName + ".xls";
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

Comment: Worth noting the main reason this works is because it's using an escape sequence and the original code in the question did not!

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the filename in quotes:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + reportName + "\".xls");
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using verbatim string for this

```
string  reportName = @"Facebook Network Performance Summary Report (By Region, By Content)";
```

Comment: This. It's not escaping the string literals properly if you don't use `\` or a verbatim string.

Comment: You're saying there is a difference between the strings:  `@"Facebook Network Performance Summary Report (By Region, By Content)";` 

and `"Facebook Network Performance Summary Report (By Region, By Content)"`?

Answer (score 1):

try adding the @ and/or double-double quotes before the double quotes to make c# read literals

[Problem with spaces in a filepath - commandline execution in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185633/problem-with-spaces-in-a-filepath-commandline-execution-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

var fileName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(document.FileName, Encoding.UTF8);